# python increment counter if character in list and then if character not in list

Tags: python, list, counter, increment

just wondering if there is a better method to accomplish the following:

i want to:

1) check if `line[0]` is a string number, if true set `counter = 1`

2) go to the next line, again check if `line[0]` is a string number, if false, continue to increment the counter *UNTIL IT FINDS A STRING NUMBER IN `line[0]`

3) if it finds a string number in `line[0]` restart counter aka set `counter = 1`

below is a sample of the file:

```
555 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
r
 a
  n
   d
    o
     m
      data
888 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
r
 a
  n
   d
    o
     m
      data
```

my results are (and should be) :

```
1 555 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2 r
3  a
4   n
5    d
6     o
7      m
8       data
1 888 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2 r
3  a
4   n
5    d
6     o
7      m
8       data
```

here is my code and i hope someone can update it... or in other words, how would you do it? thanks

```
list1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']
counter = {}

with open('O:/py_files/countlines.txt', 'rb') as infile,\
open('O:/py_files/countlines_out.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    for line in infile:

        if line[0] in list1:
            counter = 1
            outfile.writelines(str(counter) + ' ' + line)
            print str(counter) + ' ' + line

        elif line[0] not in list1:
            counter = counter + 1
            outfile.writelines(str(counter) + ' ' + line)
            print str(counter) + ' ' + line

        else:
            outfile.writelines('something went wrong...')
            print 'something went wrong...'
```

Comment: Use str.isdigit() ;-)

Comment: BTW, `counter = {}` initializes `counter` to an empty `dict`. This is **not** what you want to do here, since later in the code `counter` is just used as an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `if` statment can be used to simplfy the whole code.

```
with open('O:/py_files/countlines.txt', 'rb') as infile,\
open('O:/py_files/countlines_out.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
   counter = 1
   for line in infile:
        if line[0].isdigit():
                counter = 1

        out = str(counter)+' '+line
        outfile.write(out)
        counter += 1
```

`isdigit()` method of string checkes whether the string is decimal of not.

`"123".isdigit()
True`

`"hello".isdigit()
False`

The `counter` is intented to be an integer. Hence `counter={}` is useless. If you want you can initailize `counter=1`
It is not necessary as the first line in the input starts with digit, the `if` evaluvates `True` here initializing the `counter` for you.

The program is intented to write for each line it reads. so the write statement can be kept outside the `if`.

The `else` statement is useless. `if line[0] in list` and `if line[0] not in list` are mutually exclusive. The program will never reach `else`

Comment: just tried your code and i receive a `TypeError: must be string or buffer, not tuple` i agree that the program should never reach `else` but should you always have an `else` when creating `if` statements 'just in case'? .... `outfile.writelines(out)` fixed it

Comment: also, why is the comma used at the end of `out = str(counter)+' '+line,` i tried it with and without the comma and got the same results? thanks

Comment: Sorry, typing mistake. remove the `,` from the line ` out = str(counter)+' '+line,` make it as `out = str(counter)+' '+line`. Answer edited

Comment: another ?, just for clarification, the `counter += 1` at the end of the program continues to increment due to `line[0].isdigit()` proving `false` correct?

Comment: Only use `else` when you actually need it, otherwise you're just adding unnecessary clutter to the code. And you should **never** have something like `if line[0] in mylist:` and `elif line[0] not in mylist:` because the conditions are mutually exclusive, thus the test in the `elif` branch is **totally* redundant.

Comment: Dude I was the first one giving you the answer, it's not fair... Check the time of each answer!  We are not here to write the entire code for you, there are rules on SO.

Comment: `else` is an optional part of `if`. If the `else` is not reachable section in the program there is no point in adding that. `counter += 1` increaments the counter each time the output is printed. The `if` ensures that it is reset to `ONE`

Comment: aa ok i understand.. `The if ensures that it is reset to one` once `line[0].isdigit()` proves true `counter = 1`. thanks everyone, i am a work in progress and i am by no means a master.

Comment: No worries, nu11p01n73R . Also consider what your code will do if the first line in infile does not start with a digit.

Comment: @PM2Ring yeah i thought of that, but the question was not clear on stating it. so assumed it as such. placing `counter = 1` before `for` will solve the issue

Comment: True, the question was not clear on stating it. So you could've asked jes516 for clarification instead of posting code that will crash if the first line in infile does not start with a digit. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
for line in infile.read().splitlines():
    counter = 1 if line.split()[0].isdigit() else counter + 1
```

Comment: @Apero yes it did, thank you. again, i am still learning so the code below made more sense to me (not to discredit your answer) but i am new to py.

Comment: You can replace `for line in infile.read().splitlines():` simply with `for line in infile:`

Comment: Apero, as I said to nu11p01n73R, consider what this code will do if the first line in infile does not start with a digit.

Comment: `for line in infile.read().splitlines():` & `for line in infile:` both work. is there a specific reason to use `.read().splitlines()` ?

Comment: @jes516 : It depends whether you want the lines you're processing to end in '\n' or not. The `read().splitlines()` version strips off the trailing '\n', the `for line in infile:` doesn't. Also, `read().splitlines()` has to read the whole file into memory before the loops starts, the other version only reads & stores one line at a time, so it's much better if you're processing huge files. You can always strip off whitespace at the end of a string using the `str` `.strip()` method.

Comment: Yes, I considered all this, but are we here to rewrite the entire OP's code, add logic,  errors catching, etc? No.

Comment: Ok. I'll pay that, Apero.

Answer (score 1):

You can use isdigit() as shown below:

```
if line[0].isdigit():
    # Your Code
```

Answer (score 1):

counter = 0
for line in infile:

```
    if line[0].isdigit():
        counter = 1
    else:
        counter += 1

    out = str(counter)+' '+line,
    outfile.write(out)
```

if line[0] is a digit counter will be one or else it will increment the counter.

Answer (score 1):

[`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise. For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent.